# AOSP repo sync error , invalid index-pack output

Tags: android, android-source, repo

I what download AOSP 6.0.0 but always failed .
has any one could help me ?

My evironment : lenovo r720 computer

```
1. Ubuntu24 docker container on Ubuntu 18 OS
2. 
12:02:45 root@aospDocker ubuntu → python /mount_point/vm/AOSP/bin/repo --version
<repo not installed>
repo launcher version 2.42
       (from /mount_point/vm/AOSP/bin/repo)
git 2.43.0
Python 3.12.2 (main, Feb  7 2024, 20:47:03) [GCC 13.2.0]
OS Linux 5.4.0-150-generic (#167~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 24 00:51:42 UTC 2023)
CPU x86_64 (x86_64)
Bug reports: https://issues.gerritcodereview.com/issues/new?component=1370071
3. my device memory is 24G , swap space 2G
```

my docker info

```
tom@tom-pc ➜  ~ sudo docker run  --interactive --tty -m 20GB --cpuset-cpus='0-7'   \
   --name=aosp_container_new                                                                           \
   --hostname='aospDocker'                                                                                    \
   --mount='type=bind,source=/media/tom/samsung_ssd/vm,target=/mount_point/vm,readonly=false'  \
   --mount='type=bind,source=/media/tom/software,target=/mount_point/software,readonly=false'  \
   --detach                                                                                                 \
   0tom0/aopp_ubuntu24.04:2
WARNING: Your kernel does not support swap limit capabilities or the cgroup is not mounted. Memory limited without swap.
27ecb9dd05eb01a7c9a1a121389941db3bd76762f381dffd2f4541ea4108838e
```

My error info  , one:

```
ubuntu@aospDocker:/mount_point/vm/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1$ python /mount_point/vm/AOSP/bin/repo sync -j8 platform/external/skia 2>&1 | tee -a /mount_point/vm/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1.tmp/log/docker.ubuntu24.repo.sync.j8.[platform.external.skia].1.log  
error: Cannot fetch platform/external/skia from https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/skia

fatal: cannot read existing object 3afae70a48cd9f9c0f57dc7db3f31aea0bb158f1
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output

platform/external/skia:
fatal: cannot read existing object 3afae70a48cd9f9c0f57dc7db3f31aea0bb158f1
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
platform/external/skia: sleeping 4.0 seconds before retrying
fatal: cannot read existing object 3afae70a48cd9f9c0f57dc7db3f31aea0bb158f1
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
error: Cannot fetch platform/external/skia from https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/skia
error: Cannot checkout platform/external/skia: ManifestInvalidRevisionError: revision refs/tags/android-6.0.0_r1 in platform/external/skia not found
error: in `sync -j8 platform/external/skia`: revision refs/tags/android-6.0.0_r1 in platform/external/skia not found

fatal: cannot read existing object 3afae70a48cd9f9c0f57dc7db3f31aea0bb158f1
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output

platform/external/skia:
fatal: cannot read existing object 3afae70a48cd9f9c0f57dc7db3f31aea0bb158f1
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
platform/external/skia: sleeping 4.0 seconds before retrying
fatal: cannot read existing object 3afae70a48cd9f9c0f57dc7db3f31aea0bb158f1
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
```

My error info  , two:

```
ubuntu@aospDocker:/mount_point/vm/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1$ python /mount_point/vm/AOSP/bin/repo sync -j8 platform/external/deqp 2>&1 | tee -a /mount_point/vm/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1.tmp/log/docker.ubuntu24.repo.sync.j8.[platform.external.deqp].1.log                                                                                                                         
error: Cannot fetch platform/external/deqp from https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/deqp

fatal: serious inflate inconsistency
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output

platform/external/deqp:
fatal: serious inflate inconsistency
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
platform/external/deqp: sleeping 4.0 seconds before retrying
error: inflate: data stream error (incorrect data check)
fatal: serious inflate inconsistency
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
```

I have try the three things :

1. On mac os i always download aosp 6.0.0 success .
2. On Ubuntu 18 always download aosp 6.0.0 failed. try many times , always failed.
3. On Ubuntu 24 always download aosp 6.0.0 failed. try many times , always failed.

I hope download aosp 6.0.0 by ubuntu OS .

Comment: I would suggest you to make sure the repo launcher has read, write and execute permissions (chmod a+wrx). After this, you should delete the .repo directory completely where you have tried the repo init/sync command; followed by init and sync. Use a less job count with fail fast option.

Answer (score 0):

I never sync success on my `lenovo r720` . I have tried Ubuntu 18~Ubuntu24 , all failed . I have tried change python version python 3.6 ~ python 3.12 , all failed . I have replace my hdd to sdd , still failed.

- I gauss that my Wireless network card has some problem , that make my network unstable .  but i can't prove it .

On my Mac PC  , I'm almost never failed . When i sycn code success on my mac , i copy it to my `Lenovo r720 Ubuntu` .
Next is a little software info on mac OS  :

```
12:09:30 tom@TomdeMBP-9 aosp → python .repo/repo/repo --version
repo version v2.41
       (from https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/git/git-repo/)
       (tracking refs/heads/stable)
       (Thu, 25 Jan 2024 21:32:58 +0000)
repo launcher version 2.40
       (from /Volumes/MacOs_disk/AOSP/aosp/.repo/repo/repo)
       (currently at 2.41)
repo User-Agent git-repo/2.41 (Darwin) git/2.41.0 Python/3.11.6
git 2.41.0
git User-Agent git/2.41.0 (Darwin) git-repo/2.41
Python 3.11.6 (main, Nov  2 2023, 04:39:40) [Clang 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)]
OS Darwin 21.6.0 (Darwin Kernel Version 21.6.0: Mon Aug 22 20:19:52 PDT 2022; root:xnu-8020.140.49~2/RELEASE_ARM64_T6000)
CPU arm64 (arm)
Bug reports: https://issues.gerritcodereview.com/issues/new?component=1370071
```

#### repo sync successed

I use the aosp mirror web site :

1. https://xtom.help/AOSP/
2. https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/help/AOSP/
3. https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/help/aosp.html

I success one method :

1. first downaload aosp-last.tar
2. repo sync

I successed two method:

1. repo init -u mirror-url -b branchName
2. repo sync

#### repo sync warring info

On the start i `repo sync` success not get any warning or error . after some days re-sync got the error :

```
12:00:51 tom@TomdeMBP-9 aosp → python /Volumes/MacOs_disk/AOSP/bin/repo2.42 sync -j4 2>&1 | tee a /Volumes/MacOs_disk/AOSP/aosp.tmp/log/repo.sync.j4.2.log
info: A new version of repo is available
warning: repo is not tracking a remote branch, so it will not receive updates
================================================================================
Repo command failed: RepoUnhandledExceptionError
    GitCommandError: 'reset --keep v2.42^0' on repo failed
stderr: error：Entry 'git_command.py' not uptodate. Cannot merge.
Fatal error: Unable to reset index file to version 'v2.42^0'.

/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/resource_tracker.py:254: UserWarning: resource_tracker: There appear to be 1 leaked semaphore objects to clean up at shutdown
  warnings.warn('resource_tracker: There appear to be %d '
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/resource_tracker.py:267: UserWarning: resource_tracker: '/mp-q1hytlzz': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
  warnings.warn('resource_tracker: %r: %s' % (name, e))
```

Resolve way :

```
cd aosp/.repo/repo/
git pull 
cd ../../
python /Volumes/MacOs_disk/AOSP/bin/repo2.42 sync -j4 2>&1 | tee a /Volumes/MacOs_disk/AOSP/aosp.tmp/log/repo.sync.j4.3.log
updating: 100% (2336/2336), success.
repo sync has finished successfully.
```